# Integrating coinsecure api give me error..?

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

I want to integrate coinsecure api in my code, Here is the url for api which I have used.

**Url :** https://github.com/coinsecure/plugins/tree/master/master/php/SwaggerClient-php

Where there are two method to install/integrate API :

1. Using composer.
2. Manual process.

So I have select second one manual Process so based on document information

1. Download all file and add into my third part library folder.
2. And add require_ones autoload.php file.

Up to this step it'll fine but problem is now occur when I have perform action using this coin secure.

Suppose I want to get lowest rate over the last 24 hours so for that one bellow code is provided by api.

**Code :**

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\ExchangeTradeDataApi();
$accept = "accept_example"; // string | JSON, XML or CSV can be returned (Optional)

try {
    $result = $api_instance->v1exchangemin24Hr($accept);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling ExchangeTradeDataApi->v1exchangemin24Hr: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

And when I run this code it'll give me error as below :

> [404] Error connecting to the API
>   (https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/exchange/max24Hr)

Can any one have idea why it give me error..?

Comment: Did you include your API keys anywhere? I've never used coinsecure but it looks like you need to include authorization headers with your request.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, there's an extra `/` in your URL before the `v1` causing a 404 error. Instead it should be https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/exchange/max24Hr

Looks like their PHP library is hard coded wrong.
From their github library line 76

```
 if ($apiClient == null) {
            $apiClient = new ApiClient();
            $apiClient->getConfig()->setHost('https://api.coinsecure.in/');
        }
```

Then they include the `/` again on line 136

```
$resourcePath = "/v1/exchange/ask/low";
```

Notice how the base url ends with a `/` and the path starts with a `/`. You can change it yourself and it should work, but I bet the other calls in the library are messed up too. Maybe let them know so they can correct the library.

Location: plugins/master/php/SwaggerClient-php/lib/Api/ExchangeTradeDataApi.php

Comment: Thank for pointing me but that I had already triy but it'll give me same error

Comment: It still says 404 error can't connect to (https://api.coinsecure.in//v1/exchange/max24Hr)?  If there's 2 slashes before v1 then you are still going to get a 404. I'm able to pull the JSON fine when hitting this URL https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/exchange/max24Hr

Comment: Yes I got it your point, Also remove that '//' from that url but it still giving me same error with single '/' in url